# Class method not returning dictionary but the instance itself

Tags: python

Fairly new to Python with a question regarding class instances. I have something like

```
class Headers:
  def login_headers(self):
    return {
      'origin': 'address.com',
      'accept-encodig': 'gzip, deflate, br',
      'more': '...'
    }
```

In my main file I'm importing `from headers import Headers` and call an instance and assign it to a variable:

`headers = Headers()`

But when I want to get the dictionary out it like this:

`headers.login_headers` it does not return the dictionary but the instance itself.

The print output I'm getting is: `<bound method Headers.login_headers of <headers.Headers instance at 0x10e1d4488>`

Why is it not returning the dict?

Answer (score 3):

Because is a method.

For it to be not callable make it property with [`@property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) decorator.

```
class Headers:
    @property
    def login_headers(self):
        return {
            'origin': 'address.com',
            'accept-encodig': 'gzip, deflate, br',
            'more': '...'
        }
```

For it to be more pythonic, i woud suggest using method and call it appropriate

```
class Headers:
    def __init__(self):
        self.login_headers = {
            'origin': 'address.com',
            'accept-encodig': 'gzip, deflate, br',
            'more': '...'
        }

    def get_login_headers(self):
        return self.login_headers

headers = Headers()
headers.get_login_headers()
```

In instance initialization you would assign default value of `login_headers` and if you need to inherit you `Headers` class you can just override your `get_login_headers` to match your possible changes.

Comment: coming from the Ruby world this is something I have overseen. Is `@property` some magic Python decorator? Also does the method behave the same as when I would do `.login_headers()`?

Comment: No, it doesn't need to be called when value is retrieved, it some sort of lazy-evaluated attribute.

Comment: any downsides of this, I don't wanna attach myself to bad habits. Is using `@property` totally fine or should I actually call the method with `()`

Comment: @supersize i've updated answer with more pythonic way.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the parantheses for your method. You're getting the address of the method function instead of the method itself. Try the following:

```
headers.login_headers()
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do to actually *call* login_headers is just:

```
    headers = Headers()
    headers.login_headers()
```

login_headers is a function that you've defined as a child of the Headers class, so you just need to call it like any other function.

Comment: thanks, totally did miss that